# Print the following 1 2 3 4 Bus 6 7 8 9 bUs 11 12 13 14 buS

Tags: java

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
int n=sc.nextInt();
for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
{
    if(i%3==2 && i%5==0)
    {
        System.out.println("Bus");
    }
    if(i%3==1 && i%5==0)
    {
        System.out.println("bUs");
    }
    if(i%3==0 && i%5==0)
    {
        System.out.println("buS");
    }
System.out.println(i+" ");
}
```

The above program is also printing the number 5,10,15 but these should not print

Comment: `System.out.println(i+" ");` What makes you think this line will ever *not* execute?

Comment: You might want to use `if else` statement so you don't enter another `if` if you already printed something for that number.

Comment: The `System.out.println(i+" ");` at the end prints every number. Hint: `else`.

Comment: This is just an alternative `FizzBuzz` question, I recommend looking up solutions to that for examples to compare to your implementation (though your current problem is obvious).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
int n=sc.nextInt();
for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
{
    if(i%3==2 && i%5==0)
    {
        System.out.println("Bus");
    }
    else if(i%3==1 && i%5==0)
    {
        System.out.println("bUs");
    }
    else if(i%3==0 && i%5==0)
    {
        System.out.println("buS");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(i+" ");
    }
}
```

System.out.println does not mean it will not go through the next piece of code. You need either an else as above, or a switch statement or a break after the println.

So to explain fully, when i = 5

it goes to the first if statement, prints Bus, checks the second and third if statements and fails both, then it also runs the last println because there is no if statement around it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();

        String result =
                IntStream.range(1, Math.min(n, 100)).mapToObj(x ->
                        {
                            if (x % 5 == 0) {
                                switch (x % 3) {
                                    case 2:
                                        return "Bus";
                                    case 1:
                                        return "bUs";
                                    case 0:
                                        return "buS";
                                }
                            }
                            return x + "";
                        }
                ).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```